Flutter SSL Pinning HandshakeExeption
I'm trying to learn how to do SSL Pinning in Flutter with my movie catalog app I've made using https://api.themoviedb.org/3/. I think the certificate that I used is correct and I don't what is causing this error :
Exception has occurred.
HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393)))

I've tried using google and cloudflare dns but the result is still the same.
My Code :
static const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

  Future<SecurityContext> get globalContext async {
    try {
      final sslCert = await rootBundle.load('certificates/certificates.pem');
      print('Certificate loaded successfully.');
      SecurityContext securityContext =
          SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);
      securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(sslCert.buffer.asInt8List());
      return securityContext;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading certificate: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<List<MovieModel>> getNowPlayingMovies() async {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient(context: await globalContext);
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => false;
    IOClient ioClient = IOClient(client);
    final response =
        await ioClient.get(Uri.parse('$BASE_URL/movie/now_playing?$API_KEY'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return MovieResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).movieList;
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }



The certificate you show in the window is not the original certificate of the website, but one generated in the context of SSL interception by your antivirus (Kaspersky). This certificate will not work for pinning if the application directly connects to the website (without some Kaspersky AV in between), which it likely does. Switch off your AV or at least the SSL interception to get the real certificate of the site.

Thanks, that's solves the problem
